# VirtualHost for a subdomain and any domain

Tags: apache-2.2

I've set up a VM running CentOS to use as a development server, and I'm adding rules to my host (Windows) hosts file, so dev.site.com, live.site.com gets redirected to the VM, which are then detected by VirtualHosts. Here's are my VirtaulHosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/WebRoot/dev/
    ServerName dev.site.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/WebRoot/live/
    ServerName live.site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In the future I'm going to have lots of different domains pointing there, and I want to set it up so if I go to phpmyadmin.thedomain.(com|co.uk), the DocumentRoot is set to `/usr/local/phpmyadmin/`.

Can I set up wildcards, so for example `ServerName phpmyadmin.*.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use ServerAlias with a wildcard to accomplish this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/WebRoot/phpmyadmin/
ServerName phpmyadmin.site.com
ServerAlias phpmyadmin.*
</VirtualHost>
```

Documentation for your version can be found here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias